# Lens to optimize field of view through a tube

Tags: optics

I have a tube of length L and radius R with L>>R. I want to place a lens in the tube such that I have the biggest field of view when I look through the tube. Is the correct answer just the obvious answer that you want a short focal length lens placed at the end of the tube?

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you use can use more than one lens. The lens at the far aperture needs to be very short focal length ($f_1$) convex or Plano-convex lens. This will be able to accept light from a wide field of view and focus it to a point $A$ inside the tube. Next you place another lens of focal length $f_2$ at point $B=A-f_2$. This will collimate the light, such that it travels parallel to the axis of the tube to point $C$. Where you place your final lens that you use to form an image.